# AlarmManager executed even if the time is wrong

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code to execute the Alarm at 10:30 AM and then keep executing every 8seconds, but the problem is, this code execute the Alarm manager even when the time is not 10:30.

I have tried everything but the code keep executing the Alarm regardless of what time is set,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast */
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        startAt10();
    }

    public void startAt10() {

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        /* Set the alarm to start at 10:30 AM */
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

        /* Repeating on every 8 seconds interval */
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000 * 8, pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

and this is my `AlarmReceiver` class,

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
        Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome Back ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

I have also added this in my `AndroidManifest.xml`,

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.test2.AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true" >
    </receiver>
```

How to make it to only execute at 10:30AM ?

Comment: Do  you want it to repeat or **not**?

Comment: I want it to repeat after every 8seconds etc, but it should first execute at 10:30 then start repeating every 8seconds. However it is not hapening , no matter what the time is, it fires alarm and then fires it every 8seconds.

Comment: Is the time being **after** the 10:30? If, so, the AlarmMAnager fires **immediately** (it thinks it's **late**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. The alarm will start at 10:30 am and repeats at every 8 seconds. But once check the time in the device or emulator in which your app is running. If the time is already past then the alarm starts executing immediately.

If the time is not completed then once uninstall the application and run again it may work.